# Interleave of two lists via recursive function (Ocaml)

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I am in front of quite a challenge here, and hope that you can provide a little help.

I have tried and searched a lot, but without success.

Here is the problem:

Two lists

```
List1 : [a1; a2; ...; an]
List2 : [b1; b2; ...; bn]
```

What is the function that returns a list of ALL the interleaves possible of the two lists RESPECTING the order within each list.

For example :

```
myFunction [1; 2] ['a'; 'b'; 'c'] = [ 
    [1; 2; 'a'; 'b'; 'c']; 
    [1; 'a'; 2; 'b'; 'c']; 
    [1; 'a'; 'b'; 2; 'c']; 
    [1; 'a'; 'b'; 'c'; 2]; 
    ['a'; 1; 2; 'b'; 'c']; 
    ['a'; 1; 'b'; 2; 'c']; 
    ['a'; 1; 'b'; 'c'; 2]; 
    ['a'; 'b'; 1; 2; 'c']; 
    ['a'; 'b'; 1; 'c'; 2]; 
    ['a'; 'b'; 'c'; 1; 2] 
]
```

For those who have noticed, it is basically thinking about 2 concurrent programs, and ALL the executions possible when the 2 programs are launched (1 is always before 2, a is always before b and before c, otherwise, all interleaves are possible)

I hope that I was clear, and that you can help me.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Second question: what answer do you want for `myFunction [1] [1]`?  Also an observation: your example is invalid OCaml-- you can't have a list of mixed characters and ints.  (But the idea is clear.)

Comment: It is just a fragment of a much bigger homework assignment.

And myFunction [1] [1] would return [ [1; 1]; [1; 1] ], it is all possible ways for the two lists.

For my example, I just wanted to make it clearer, as I thought that 2 lists of numbers would confuse. Hope that is okay.

Thank you a lot

Comment: Great!  Since you allow duplicates, I'd say pad's hints look excellent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it is homework, here are a few hints:

1). The function would take two lists of same type `'a list` and return an `'a list list`.

```
val interleave: 'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list list
```

2). If one list is empty, the result is a singleton list consisting of the other one.
3). Let's say you would like to execute `interleave` on two non-empty lists `x::xs` and `y::ys`. There are two kinds of interleaving. The first kind has `x` as the head of resulting lists, you would put `x` into the beginning of any list returning from `interleave xs (y::ys)`. The second kind has `y` as the new head, you would prepend `y` into any list obtaining from `interleave (x::xs) ys`.

With these hints, I think you are able to create a recursive function with a few pattern matching cases to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey and thank you Pad.

Your hints are helpful, I am taking them (and those you gave in an old post about merging list in F#) into account.

A little stuck with "Symmetrically, you would prepend y into any list in the list of lists from interleave (x::xs) ys" as I think it is my missing puzzle piece.

Thank you

Comment: To see how this works (BTW), what helped me was to realize that if both lists are non-null, there are only two kinds of interleaving.  One kind starts with the head of one list.  The other kind starts with the head of the other list.  This is enough to derive pad's analysis (by recursion).

Answer (score 3):

```
(* Each interleaving of non-empty lists lst1 = [x1; x2; ...; xm]
   and lst2 = [y1; y2; ...; yn] begins either with x1 or with y1.
   Thus we may get all the interleavings as follows:

   1. Compute all interleavings of [x2; ...; xm] and [y1; ...; yn]
      and prepend x1 to each one of them.

   2. Compute all interleavings of [x1; ...; xm] and [y2; ...; yn]
      and prepend y1 to each one of them.

   Append the lists obtained in steps 1 and 2 to get all possible
   interleavings. The border cases is when either one of the lists
   is empty, but that is easy to figure out. Here is the corresponding
   code.
*)

let rec interleave lst1 lst2 =
  match lst1, lst2 with
    | [], ys -> [ys]
    | xs, [] -> [xs]
    | x :: xs, y :: ys ->
        (List.map (fun zs -> x :: zs) (interleave xs (y::ys))) @
        (List.map (fun zs -> y :: zs) (interleave (x::xs) ys))
```

Test case:

```
# interleave [1;2] [100;200;300] ;;
- : int list list =
[[1; 2; 100; 200; 300]; [1; 100; 2; 200; 300]; [1; 100; 200; 2; 300];
[1; 100; 200; 300; 2]; [100; 1; 2; 200; 300]; [100; 1; 200; 2; 300];
[100; 1; 200; 300; 2]; [100; 200; 1; 2; 300]; [100; 200; 1; 300; 2];
[100; 200; 300; 1; 2]]
```

NB: In Ocaml lists are monomorphic so we cannot interleave strings and integers, as was suggested in the question. Or to put it in a different way, for that we would have to use
a sum type.